# python: Pick the x amount of biggest numbers from list, but I get TypeError - NoneType

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype, iterable

I'am new to python. I tried to write this code but I always get a TypeError.
This is the task:

finds the length_subset biggest values in a

Parameters
a:
array to find the biggest values in
length_subset:
length of subset
Returns
maximum_values:
maximum values. Ordered in ascending order. [] if a is empty or length_subset is zero, ordered values of a if length_subset is bigger than length(a).
maximum_indizes:
corresponding indices. [] if a is empty or length_subset is zero.

This is the code:

```
def maximum_subset(a, length_subset):
 
    if len(a) == 0 or length_subset == 0:
        return [],[]
    

    if len(a) <= length_subset:
        copied_list = a.copy()
        sorted_list = copied_list.sort(reverse = True)
        maximum_values = sorted_list
        maximum_indizes = []
        for i in sorted_list:
            maximum_indizes.append(a.index(i))
        
        return maximum_values, maximum_indizes
    
    if len(a) > length_subset:
        copied_list = a.copy()
        sorted_list = copied_list.sort(reverse = True)
        maximum_values = []
        for j in range(length_subset + 1):
            maximum_values.append(sorted_list[j])

        return maximum_values, maximum_indizes
        

a = [5, 1, 9, -4, 0, 3]    # input
maximum_subset(a,10)       # input
```

This is the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [146], in <cell line: 44>()
     40         return maximum_values, maximum_indizes
     43 a = [5, 1, 9, -4, 0, 3]
---> 44 maximum_subset(a,10)

Input In [146], in maximum_subset(a, length_subset)
     26 maximum_values = sorted_list
     27 maximum_indizes = []
---> 28 for i in sorted_list:
     29     maximum_indizes.append(a.index(i))
     31 return maximum_values, maximum_indizes

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Does anyone know how fix this?

Thanks

Comment: use `sorted(lst,reverse=True)` instead of `lst.sort`. `lst.sort` can be called by itself and does not need to be assigned to anything. `sorted`, however, returns the sorted version of the lst.

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort` doesn't return anything - it just modifies the original list.

You don't need to define the variable `sorted_list` - just use `maximum_values = copied_list` after sorting and replace `for i in sorted_list` with `for i in copied_list` etc.